# Efficient way to detect color using Frame Mat OpenCV Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera2, color-detection

In order to calculate the average rgb color of a given frame, I am using the following for each loops to get the average color.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pFrame.cols(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < pFrame.rows(); j++) {
                        int pixel_rgb_avg = ((int)(pFrame.get(i, j)[0] + pFrame.get(i, j)[1] + pFrame.get(i, j)[2]) / 3);
                        r_curr += pFrame.get(i, j)[0];
                        g_curr += pFrame.get(i, j)[1];
                        b_curr += pFrame.get(i, j)[2];
                        counter_curr += 1;

                    }
    }
    r_curr = r_curr/ counter_curr;
    g_curr = g_curr/ counter_curr;
    b_curr = b_curr/ counter_curr;
```

This works fine, but this task has to be done in realtime. Depending on the matsize it can take a long time to finish this procedure, probably caused by the get() method which is invoked three times each iteration. (It is done in a background thread)

Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mean()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461) returns the average value per channel and should be faster than your code.

Comment: This is a good way to do it. Furthermore I need to exclude specific pixels which do not fit a threshold but therefore I still need to iterate through all pixels, right?

Comment: Yes, in the general case you would need to process pixel by pixel, but if you specify the details in another question me or someone else might be able to find a more optimized solution.